# Erro Ajax - fim inesperado dos dados

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou tentando descobrir o que está ocorrendo com o código ajax abaixo. Se a string vem com dados, funciona corretamente, mas se ela vem vazia, ocorre o erro:

> JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Se eu der um alert no `var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);` que é onde dá o erro, ela está vazia, mas não entra na exceção que fiz: `if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {`

Alguma idéia de onde posso estar errando?

UPDATE

Ajax completo:

```js
/**
  * Função para criar um objeto XMLHTTPRequest
  */
 function CriaRequest() {
     try{
         request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (IEAtual){

         try{
             request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(IEAntigo){

             try{
                 request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(falha){
                 request = false;
             }
         }
     }

     if (!request)
         alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
     else
         return request;
}

//Não executa nada até a execução terminar
var requestActive = false;

function getDados() {
    if (requestActive) return;
    requestActive = true;
    // Declaração de Variáveis
    /* Caso for necessário passar mais parametros além do nome
     * basta adicionar uma variável aqui e editar no GET
     */
    var ids = ["usuario", "senha", "email", "admin", "cod_setor", "nome_completo", "ativo", "habilitacao", "categoria"];
    var cracha = document.getElementById("cracha").value; //CAMPO QUE VEM DO INDEX.PHP
    var result = document.getElementById("content"); //DIV DE RETORNO DOS DADOS
    var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

    // Exibe a mensagem de progresso
    //result.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Progresso.gif"/>';
    ids.forEach(function (id) {
        document.getElementById(id).value = 'Aguarde...';
    });

    // Iniciar uma requisição
    // Se for colocar mais variáveis, é aqui. Exemplo: processa.php?txtnome=" + nome + '&admissao=' + admissao
    xmlreq.open("GET", "processaMotorista.php?cracha=" + cracha, true);

    // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de estado
    xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
        if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
            // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
                //Se o retorno foi vazio do Oracle
                if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {
                    document.getElementById("nome_completo").focus();
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                    });
                //Se encontrou dados
                } else {
                    //Aqui recebe os dados do processa.php, abre e aplica nos campos desejados
                    var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                    // função para preencher os campos com os dados
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = dados[id];
                    });
                }
            } else {
                result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
            }
        }
        requestActive = false;
    };
    xmlreq.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Está dizendo que o fim dos dados está na linha 2, então a resposta não está vazia. Tente usar um depurador pra ver o que está acontecendo.

Comment: No firebug não aparece nada. Aparece o erro, mas não tem dados.

Comment: Tente adicionar `console.log(xmlreq.responseText);` e depois verifique o console.

Comment: Ou Coloque um breakpoint nessa linha e análise o valor da variável antes de deixar executar.

Comment: Fiz isso, a variável vem nula, mas passa direto pelo if, como se tivesse algo nela. Coloquei o console.log(xmlreq.responseText); mas não mudou nada

Comment: @Diego se ela vem nula(NULL), você deve fazer essa segunda verificação tbm. NULL é diferente de Vazio. Altere seu if para verificar se ela está vindo Vazia, nula ou com espaço em branco("",null, " ")

Comment: Fiz os 3 testes e retornou o mesmo erro. Não faço idéia do que ocorreu, mas outros 3 ajax que usam basicamente a mesma sintaxe também pararam.

Comment: @Diego Use um depurador para parar a execução antes de entrar no IF e olhe o valor **exato** dela pelo inspetor. Console.log pode enganar porque várias coisas têm uma representação que parece vazia.

Comment: Que depurador poderia usar @Pablo?

Comment: O depurador do seu navegador preferido. No Firefox, aperte F12, vá até a aba Depurar e clique no lado esquerdo da linha do IF para colocar um ponto de parada lá. Quando seu código executar, ao chegar nessa linha, a execução para.

Comment: Diego, o problema foi resolvido?

Comment: Sim, descobri que tinha um espaço a mais onde montava a string. Removi ele e voltou a funcionar.